# PickedFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File' error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, imagepicker

Im trying to make an app that will open the camera and take a photo and load it using flutter. First I used pickImage but I got this message **'pickImage' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use imagePicker.getImage() method instead..**

so I used getImage method...

```
_openCamera(BuildContext context) async{
var picture =await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
this.setState(() {
  imageFile= picture;
});
```

but then this error came when I used the below code
**The argument type 'PickedFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.**

```
 if(imageFile==null){
  return Text("No selected Image");
}else{
  Image.file(imageFile,width: 400,height: 400);
}
```

Please help me .I'm very new to flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PickedFile`, which is the type returned by `imagePicker`, is a type specific to `image_picker` package, hence it's not the same as `File`.

You can do the following to convert it to `File`:

```dart
Image.file(File(imageFile.path), width: 400, height: 400);
```